# How to add where on count() in joined table?

Tags: php, laravel

How do I add the where clause only on the `count()`? Using `->where('point',1)` will affect the end result of the whole table and that's not what I want. I want to calculate the count of points where it's  grouped by the child_id and the point column equals `1`.

```
 $chore_contents = DB::table('chores_content')   
        ->join('children', 'children.id', '=', 'chores_content.child_id')  
        ->select('chores_content.id as content_id','chores_content.*', 'children.*', DB::raw("COUNT(point) as points"))        
        ->where('chores_content.user_id', Auth::id())
        ->where('chores_content.chores_id', $id)  
        ->groupBy('chores_content.child_id')     
        ->get();
        return $chore_contents;
```

Comment: your question doesn't include an ERD.  The immediate problem I see is that if you groupBy, you get 1 row per grouping.  When you count(somecolumn) all you are going to do is get a count where that column is not null.  It is not a SUM, so I'm not sure why you are specifying a count(point) as points, when that is going to be the same value as count(*) unless you have null point values.

Comment: I have null points values but only columns with value 1 should be counted

Comment: According to laravel docs count doesn't work without grouping

Comment: then your  where clause of `->where('point',1)` should be used.  At this point you need some examples of the result vs. the result you want or people won't be able to help you further.

Comment: If I do it like that the result will not include the objects where the point column has null values. I don't want that to be affected. All I need is to add an extra property I.e. "points":12, calculated from the number of rows where the column point is 1

Answer (score 0):

Use havingRaw to implement this:

```
$chore_contents = DB::table('chores_content')   
    ->join('children', 'children.id', '=', 'chores_content.child_id')  
    ->select('chores_content.id as content_id','chores_content.*', 'children.*',  DB::raw("COUNT(point) as points"))        
    ->where('chores_content.user_id', Auth::id())
    ->where('chores_content.chores_id', $id)  
    ->groupBy('chores_content.child_id') 
    ->havingRaw('COUNT(point) =1')    
    ->get();
    return $chore_contents;
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: That's affecting the whole table. The result is not returning the correct respond. Where there is Null in point column the respond is missing.

Comment: I am still need to see expected result if possible

Comment: Without the count() I get 3 objects. With what you suggested I get only 2 probably because 1 object's column point has null values? What I'm trying to do is to add another property into an array which would return the count of points

Comment: You need to understand what group by does.  You will get a row for every unique group.  You are grouping by chores_content.child_id, so you will get 1 row per child_id.  COUNT() is the number of rows that were in that group when it was grouped together.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought the grouping is. The problem is I'm not getting the correct numbers for some reason.

Comment: I might try to change the column's  data type not to be nullable and try the default value to 0 and see if I can use sum instead.

Answer (score 0):

This question lacks some clarity, so this is simply an educated guess at this point.

First to clarify that when you do this: count(point) you already exclude rows where point is null.  You should not be count(point) if you want to include rows where point is null.

Given your comments you seem to be contradicting your statement that you only want rows where point=1.  It now appears you want rows where point = 1 or point is null.

To do this with eloquent, you would need to have parens around the (point=1 OR point IS NULL) which you can do by passing an anonymous function:

```
$chore_contents = DB::table('chores_content')   
    ->join('children', 'children.id', '=', 'chores_content.child_id')  
    ->select('chores_content.id as content_id','chores_content.*', 'children.*',  DB::raw("COUNT(*) as points"))        
    ->where('chores_content.user_id', Auth::id())
    ->where('chores_content.chores_id', $id) 
    ->where(function ($chore_contents) {
        $chore_contents->where('point',1)
            ->orWhereNull('point');
    }) 
    ->groupBy('chores_content.child_id') 
    ->havingRaw('COUNT(point) =1')    
    ->get();
return $chore_contents;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help either.

Comment: I know what the problem is. This part: `->where('chores_content.chores_id', $id)`. This limits only the rows belonging to that chore. I was trying to get total count of children points for all chores. Do you know how to include the total count of points for all chores?